# Problems with HTML5 FileReader

Tags: html, google-chrome-app, filereader

I try to run the FileReader function in my project but it only works pas.Mon project works like so I list all files in a directory. It all works. But when I select a file in the list (my files are local), I end up with this error I do not understand:

*Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': The argument is not a Blob.*

Here is my code:

```
GetFileName function (fs) {
     var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

     var childs = target.parentNode.childNodes;
     {for (i = 0; i ++; i <childs.length)
         if (target == childs [i]) break;
     }

     console.log (i); // Index li
     console.log (event.target.innerHTML); // li value

     filename = "~ / Downloads / snippets" + event.target.innerHTML;

var fr = new FileReader ();
fr.onload = function (e) {
     console.log (e.target.result);
};
fr.readAsText (filename);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of what does not work?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: The error seems clear enough. You can't feed a `filename` to it. It expects a `Blob` representation of a file or a `File` object.

Comment: I wonder how you are listing files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `filename` variable is set to:

```
filename = "~ / Downloads / snippets" + event.target.innerHTML;
```

...which is a String, rather than the object that's expected by the `readAsText` function on `FileReader`.

Try something like this instead:

```
var fileInputElement = document.getElementById("fileInputElement");
fr.readAsText(fileInputElement.files[0]);
```

Where "fileInputElement" is the ID of the HTML `<input>` element of type `file`.

This may not fit exactly with what you're doing, but it's not easy to tell without seeing more of your JavaScript and HTML.